# Wordpress rest_pre_serve_request produces PHP header warnings

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, httprequest, httpserver

I am currently developing my first Wordpress plugin and I've encountered an issue with the REST API which I don't really understand. Maybe there is a better approach than mine, that I am not yet aware of, so I am happy for any help that's out there!

*Here's the deal:*

I am creating an API that is supposed to serve cached data from the Wordpress mysql db. I am storing data (url, mime-type, [...]) from web resources to the db which I then want to serve. The resources to be cached are defined in a policy file which looks something like this:

**policy.json**

```
{
    "files":
    [
        {
            "resource_url": "https://example.come/assets/images/image.png",
            (...)
        },
        (...)
    ]
}
```

Since the number of files is dynamic my service needs to adjust to whatever custom routes the policy file dictates. E.g. In the above case it is supposed to serve the resource via my Wordpress site, which initially came from example.com. So if
`https://my-wordpress-site.com/wp-json/example/v1/assets/images/image.png` is requested, the cached file from `https://example.come/assets/images/image.png` is supposed to be served.

My REST API looks something like this:

**mypl/rest_api.php**

```
<?php

function custom_resource_endpoint() {
    return new WP_REST_Response("The requested resource could not be found.", 400);    
}


function rpc_through_endpoint( $request_data ) {

    $route = $request_data->get_route();
    $header = $request_data->get_headers();
    $data = $request_data->get_body();

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com" . str_replace('example/v1/', '', $route));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/octet-stream'));
            
41  $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
   
    return new WP_REST_Response($response, 200);
}


function register_custom_routes() {
    $rest_prefix = 'example/v1';

    register_rest_route($rest_prefix, '/rpc', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
        'callback' => 'rpc_through_endpoint'
    ));

    register_rest_route($rest_prefix, '(/w)', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'custom_resource_endpoint'
    ));    
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_custom_routes');


// Interceptor.

function serve_static_resources($served, $result, $request, $server) {

    $route = $request->get_route();

    if (ends_with($route, 'rpc')) {
        $served = false;
    } else {

        $file_uri = str_replace('/example/v1/', 'https://example/', $route);
        
        if ($file_uri != null) {
            $resource = checkLatestResourceByUri($file_uri);
            if(count($resource) > 0) {
                $vars=get_object_vars($resource[0]);
                http_response_code(200);
                header( 'Content-Type: ' . $vars['resource_mime_type'], true );
92              echo $vars['resource_data'];
                $served = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return $served;
}

add_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', 'serve_static_resources', 10, 4);
```

The way I thought about it was, I create a READABLE (GET) rest route, which accepts all requests on the rest API. Once the request comes in it is being intercepted with the `rest_pre_serve_request` filter, in order to check the database whether or not the requested file is cached and if so serve it. Here's my approach on that:

According to the documentation I can simply echo the data from the filter and return `true` or `false` to indicate whether the request has already been served or not. In my case though, I also have to add additional data such as the `Status-Code` and the `Content-Type` for the response, in order for the clients to be able to process it correctly. *Now here's the Crux.* The logic works exactly like I want it to and it serves the requests like they're supposed to be, but still I get the classic **headers already sent warnings** from PHP, which look like this:

```
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 596
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 597
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 596
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 596
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 598
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 597
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 597
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 599
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 598
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 598
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 599
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 599

[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:41) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php on line 1337
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:41) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 596
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:41) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 597
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:41) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 598
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:41) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 599

[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 596
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 596
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 596
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 597
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 597
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 597
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 598
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 598
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 598
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 599
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 599
[06-Aug-2020 10:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 599
```

Lines 41 and 92 are marked in the code above.

**So, is there anything that I am doing fundamentally wrong here?? Or maybe someone knows how to handle that pre serving stuff properly?**

**I appreciate your help!!**

Comment: So what _is_ on lines 92 and 41 of your rest_api.php? What you have shown us until now, does not even contain that many lines.

Comment: I forgot to add that. I'll do that right away.
Line 92 is "echo $vars['resource_data'];"
Line 41 is curl_exec(...) in the rpc through endpoint.

Comment: Still not enough info. Assuming that you are not calling `serve_static_resources`, which contains that echo output line, multiple times, we’d need to see what happens in the other places as well (that you so vaguely referrd to with _“on line 596, 597, 598, 599 (multiple of these)”_), we can’t currently tell where you are doing what exactly, and in what order.

Comment: Well, as far as I understand it ```serve_static_resources``` is always called bc I am hooking it up through the add_filter on every ```rest_pre_serve_request```. The errors in the 500+ lines are in the main ```.../wp-includes/rest-api.php``` files.

Comment: You can only answer one HTTP request with one response - so having that function execute multiple times during one single request, does not appear to make much sense to begin with. (Or, if that is actually necessary, then you need to implement some criterion check that makes it output headers and content only once.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm not entirely following, how do I know that the function is being executed multiple times during one request? At least if I request a file though the api manually, I can see that only the interceptor is firing. So I don't understand how it should be invoked multiple times...

Comment: I assumed you got multiple of those _“(output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mypl/rest_api.php:92)”_ each time? Or are these log entries for separate requests?

Comment: Yeah, I pasted them in for you. ^^ They are for individual requests tho. 
I have been doing some digging and the wp-rest api defaults are the issue (in wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 596). The API tries to set cors headers for all the requests and it appears as if the addition of those come after my custom pre serve requests, because both filters (the default wp and my custom one) are set to priority 10.
To resolve the issue, I've set my filter to a priority higher than the default 10 so that the invocation is definitely after the default cors headers set by wp, that resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue.

Wordpress has a default CORS filter in `.../wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 596`, in this filter Wordpress sets default headers to send "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing headers with API requests". (https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/5.4/src/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L596) This filter is added with default priority (10) to the REST API therefore I just had to give my custom filter a higher priority in oder to have it executed after the default WP CORS filter.

```
add_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', 'serve_static_resources', 11, 4);
```

And the warnings disappeared.